# Inheritance: putting parent class __init__ args in creation of child class

Tags: python

When I instantiate a `Child` class, how can I give the `Parent` class its args? Do I need to instantiate the `Parent` class with its args first, then use that object in my `Child` args?

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

object = Child()
```

Where do I put the Parent class args?

Comment: `super().__init__()` initializes the parent, so do `super().__init__(stuff)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass it into the `__init__` call for the parent.

Change `Child` to accept the args for parent and then pass them in the `__init__` function.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(args)
```